# Split string via select statement

Tags: string, split, sql-server-2012, ssms

Fairly simple question, but seems impossibe to get an answer.

If I have this:

```
declare @Agent nvarchar(4000) = '2131235,334225';
```

Is there a select statement I can write to split the string where the coma is, WITHOUT having to write a function?

Something like:

```
SELECT SOME_SPLIT_LOGIC(@Agent)
```

I would like it to return:

```
Column
--------
2131235
334225
```

Please note I am use MS-SQL 2012

Comment: A built-in function is available in SQL Server 2016 (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)), but in Sql Server 2012 I'm afraid you have to write your own split function

Comment: Do a Google search for "Jeff Moden DelimitedSplit8K".

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @LeftPart TABLE
(Agent int
)

DECLARE @RightPart TABLE
(Agent1 int
)

declare @Agent nvarchar(4000) = '2131235,334225';

INSERT INTO @LeftPart
SELECT LEFT(@Agent,7)

INSERT INTO @RightPart
SELECT RIGHT(@Agent,6)

SELECT * INTO #Temp
FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM @LeftPart
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @RightPart
)A

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DECLARE @Agent VARCHAR(4000) = '2131235,334225'
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1) = ','

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + 1 FROM CTE
    WHERE ID < 4000
)   

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@Agent, t.ID, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Agent + @Delimiter, t.ID) - t.ID) AS Agent
FROM CTE t
WHERE t.ID <= DATALENGTH(@Agent)+1
    AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @Agent, t.ID, 1) = @Delimiter
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 4000)
```

More information can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/